# calculating the position of the sun by using degrees and determining date and time

Tags: the-sun

so i found this code and  even looked up the documentation on swe_suncross() most i've seen its - 88 degrees  but can one determine this using any degrees

```
# set ephemeris files path
swe.set_ephe_path('~/Downaloads/swisseph-master/')

# birth time as Julian day number (UT), for example
birth_t = swe.julday(1988, 6, 12, 5.5)
# sun longitude at birth
sun_longitude = swe.calc_ut(birth_t, swe.SUN)[0][0]
# longitude searched
xlon = swe.degnorm(sun_longitude - 88)
# start search 90 deays prior to birth
tstart = birth_t - 90
# find exact crossing time
res = swe.solcross_ut(xlon, tstart)
# turn it into a date
date = swe.revjul(res)

print("Year:", date[0], "Month:", date[1], "Day:", date[2], "Hour:", date[3])
```

and i get sent in the future ???

`Year: 1989 Month: 3 Day: 14 Hour: 1.8550639897584915`

i have tried other numbers( less than 88 ) and was still in the future .. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This question is more about general debugging than astronomy. Inspect your intermediate values. I think you'll find `xlon` is 353.5.

Comment: Mike the xlong checks out, however the  rest is way off  ```Year: 1989 Month: 3 Day: 14
Time: 1 hours 51 minutes 18 seconds
Sun Longitude at Birth: 81.46587046324426
xlon: 353.46587046324424
tstart: 2447234.7291666665
Result (Julian Day Number): 2447599.577294333
``` thank you for the help tho <3

Comment: What's the Sun's longitude at `tstart`?

Comment: ```Sun Longitude at tstart: 353.8554640836316```

Comment: So at `tstart` the Sun is 0.39° past `xlon` and it takes another year to get there again.

Comment: This is the best I can do .. ```Sun Longitude at tstart: 352.8581509350368
xlon: 353.46587046324424```  Not sure what else to thinker with to get it spot on :(   however your guidance helped <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148721/discussion-between-dimitri33-and-mike-g).